# Where is the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Where is the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013?

I try to find it on the "View" menu, but I don't see the "Server Explorer",
is it changed into other name?

my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XSEi.png

Server Explorer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk.aspx

Comment: Do you have `Connect to Server` under `Tools` menu? What edition of visual studio do you have (enterprise, community or others)?

Comment: sorry I suddenly find that my visual studio is 2013 ultimate, sorry again...  The answer below works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **V**iew Oth**e**r Windows or `Ctrl-Alt-S`.

Comment: Thanks! I find it at "View >> Other Windows " and see the Server Explorer.
Ctrl-Alt-S works too!  Sorry I don't have the authority to vote yet.